# Evenly distribute range of specified values within a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, range

I have a vector A and I want to populate it with values as evenly as possible.  For example, if A is 1x30 and I want to use three values I would use a code like this below:

```
% A = zeros(1,30);
A([1:10])=0;
A([11:20])=1;
A([21:30])=2;
```

This works, but seems a bit cumbersome to me.  Is there a more elegant way to evenly (as possible) distribute a specified range of values within a vector? I am intent on keeping each of the values in "clumps."

Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to distribute the values `[5 2 6]` as evenly as possible on a vector of length 8. Then you can use `linspace` the following way:

```
vals = [5 2 6];
vecLength = 8;

nVals = length(vals);
idx = floor(linspace(1,nVals+1-2*eps(nVals),vecLength));

out = vals(idx)

out =

     5     5     5     2     2     6     6     6
```

Comment: Jonas, `-2*eps` seems not to be enough. It does not work on my example. Otherwise a cool idea!

Comment: @angainor: Indeed, it should be `2*eps(nVals)`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem from another direction. Define the values you want, define the vector size, replicate the vector as many times as needed obtaining a matrix, and cut out the 'excessive' elements:

```
range  = [1 3 5 7 9]';
vsize  = 52;

% number of repetitions
rep    = ceil(vsize/numel(range));

% replicate the range vector;
result = repmat(range, 1, rep);

% cut the the excessive elements
result(vsize+1:end) = NaN;
result = reshape(result', 1, []);
result(isnan(result)) = [];
```

The distribution is as even as possible, i.e., the difference in the number of occurrences of the values from the range is at most 1.